# RabbitMQ Spring dead letter config not working

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Below is the configuration I'm using. Messages with no errors, work fine from exchange to queue with conversion picked up by the listener, its great.  What I am **wanting** to happen with erroneous messages is that when I throw a **AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException**, "rabbitQueue" will forward the message to it's dead letter exchange and end up in the "rabbitErrorQueue."  There's no activity on the dead letter exchange or queue though. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    <beans
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="clientConnectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    </bean>

    <rabbit:connection-factory
            id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
            connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"
            host="${rabbit.broker.url}"
            port="${rabbit.broker.port}"
            username="${rabbit.username}"
            password="${rabbit.password}"
            publisher-confirms="true"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate"
                     connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
                     exchange="${rabbit.exchange.name}"
                     message-converter="messageConverter"
                     queue="${rabbit.queue.name}" >
    </rabbit:template>


    <rabbit:queue id="rabbitQueue" name="${rabbit.queue.name}" >
        <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="${rabbit.dead.letter.exchange.name}"/>
            <entry key="x-message-ttl" value="10000" value-type="java.lang.Long"/>
        </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>

    <rabbit:queue id="rabbitErrorQueue" name="${rabbit.dead.letter.queue.name}" />

    <rabbit:fanout-exchange id="fanoutExchange" name="${rabbit.exchange.name}">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="rabbitQueue" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:fanout-exchange>


    <rabbit:direct-exchange id="directErrorExchange" name="${rabbit.dead.letter.exchange.name}">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding key="${rabbit.queue.name}" queue="rabbitErrorQueue" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

    <bean id="messageConverter" class="com.example.RabbitMQExampleEventMessageConverter"/>

    <bean id="rabbitMQExampleConsumer" class="com.example.consumer.RabbitMQExampleConsumer">
        <constructor-arg name="eventProcessor" ref="userEventProcessor" />
    </bean>

    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="messageConverter">
        <rabbit:listener queues="${rabbit.queue.name}" ref="rabbitMQExampleConsumer" method="onMessage" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you share from where do you throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I throw the exception from the consumer "RabbitMQExampleConsumer" If something goes wrong, which for testing, I'm making sure it throws it every time.

Comment: Good. How does it work for you if you change `fanout-exchange id="fanoutExchange" ` to the `direct-exchange` ?

Comment: Try adding an explicit `x-dead-letter-routing-key` - otherwise the same key as the original route is used - and there's no routing key needed for a fanout exchange.

Comment: @GaryRussell That did it, thank you.  Would you mind putting that in as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank you as well.  Turns out both solutions worked, setting the queue name as the routing key on the direct exchange or simply making it a fanout exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an explicit `x-dead-letter-routing-key` - otherwise the same key as the original route is used - and there's no routing key needed for a fanout exchange.